# can i do "ctrl+shift+f5" shortcut in python?

Tags: python

i am work on a project. I need when

```
 if a==5:
     do: ctrl+shift+f5`
```

i run my project in Debug mode. when come a signal from arduino my code start run. But my code run just one time because of i want my code run one time after do this shortcut ctrl+shift+f5. This shortcut for restart the debug run. When i restart the debug my code is work properly.
but i dont know how to do it. please help me. i need just pseuo code. Just you say i modify this in my code. Thank you for everything

Comment: Python is a language and an interpreter - "do 'ctrl+shift+f5' shortcut" doesn't mean anything in that context.  Your question has nothing to do with any of the tags you added to the question and is probably a question about the editor or IDE you are using. Please update your question and make sure you had a look at the help / documentation for your editor before asking a question with an obvious answer.

Comment: don’t know how to do what? am I right, goal is to start py code when shortcut key is pressed?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72578899/how-to-do-ctrlshiftf5-shortcut-in-python

Comment: Why specifically ctrl+shift+f5? It sounds to me like you could probably use a _while loop_ to ask the user if the code should run again, then run the block of code